# mvc javascript multiple times

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

if have a requirement in which certain fields uses htmleditor. so for each field that uses htmleditor, i have created a editor template which renders a htmleditor by using jquery and i use UIHint for that.

```
@model System.String

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        editor_selector: "htmlmarker",
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,         justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,    |,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,     blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,    |,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup",

        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left"

    });

</script>
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model, new {@class="htmlmarker" })
```

now evreything works fine but on execution when i view source i get that the jquery scripts are referenced and called multiple times for every field that uses UIHint . is there any mechanism to prevent duplication of javascript code ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your Javascript in the editor template, that will execute **for every item that uses that template**.

Instead, put it in a separate JS file, have that JS file called on your layout, then on page load, it will be executed once and include **all** items you have assigned the class `htmlmarker` in your Editor Template.